# ssis text qualifier ignore LF CR in the field

Tags: csv, import, ssis

Is there a setting on SSIS to ignore CR and LF in the text qualified segment. I have a CSV file with a comments field where within the text qualified segment of this field there are some line breaks. Is there a way to ignore them within the text qualified segment?

Comment: And how do you determine that a new line is a new comment line instead of a new record?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: because it's enclosed inside text qualifiers, e.g. double quotes, like `txt1;txt2;"txt3\ntxt4";txt5`; maybe there is a tool to transcode that and replace that `\n` with e.g. `<br />`, however, I don't know if it exists - maybe you should just code it ;)

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a simple format that can't handle the line separator appearing inside the line itself.

It's far easier to export the data using a line separator that is guaranteed NOT to appear inside the line itself.

Most export tools allow you to specify the field and record separator. I've used `|`,`§` and even `¶` and `¤` as field and line separators many times to extract data from mainframes that did have newlines and quotes in some fields. It was far easier and faster that trying to parse the text, identifying whether a newline appeared inside multiple quotes or not.